# maven: Unrecognised tag: 'testResources'

Tags: java, maven

When I run mvn resources:testResources i obtain

```
Non-parseable POM /home/ernst/Software/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'testResources'
```

The problem seems

```
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
<directory>${resourceDir}</directory>
<filtering>true</filtering>
<includes>
  <!--include>octave/m/java-arithmetics/**/*.m</include-->
  <include>octave/octaverc</include>
  <include>octave/java.opts</include>
</includes>
  </resource>
</resources>

<testResources>
  <testResource>
<directory>${tstResourcesDir}</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
     <include>*.rml</include>
</includes>
  </testResource>
<testResources>

<plugins>
```

As long as I had only the tag resources, all was fine. 
Now that i added testResources, i have the problem. 
The resources plugin is configured as follows:

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
<configuration>
  <escapeString>\</escapeString> <!-- \${java.home} -> ${java.home} -->
      <!--nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions-->
  <!--outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory-->
</configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I have the impression, that this problem is about maven itself 
not about the resources plugin, right? 
I use maven 3.5.0.

Comment: You are not closing testResources, check your pom definition with http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-model/maven.html

Comment: Why are you using properties to define resources directories? Best is to make a separation between a filtered directory and a non filtered directory...Why do you need to define the maven-resources-plugin explicit ? And it would help to have the full pom file (github?)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that your XML is not valid:

- You didn't close `build` element
- You didn't close `testResources` element

I made few updates to your XML and built project with the following `build` section:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${resourceDir}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <!--include>octave/m/java-arithmetics/**/*.m</include-->
                <include>octave/octaverc</include>
                <include>octave/java.opts</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${tstResourcesDir}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*.rml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

It worked for me. Hope it will for you :)

Comment: Hi Danylo, well i did close the tags but i showed a snipped only.
The full pom is too long to show here. 
Maybe I shall try a minimal example and the grow it.

Comment: If you simplify you pom by replacing build section with my version of build section - does it work for you?

Comment: @user2609605 don't worry about the size of your pom.xml, you can copy/paste it in your questions and SO will make sure it shows nicely by wrapping it around a scrollable screen. Otherwise you can use https://pastebin.com/.